# Encryption between Node.JS and Laravel Converting Code

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, encryption

so I have the following code on Node.js

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

function encrypt (key = "9055935C641A3CD243337FD149C793DF", data) {
    var key  = (key instanceof Buffer) ? key : new Buffer(key, 'hex');
    var iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv( "aes-128-cbc", key, iv); 
    var result = Buffer.concat([iv, cipher.update(data), cipher.final()]);
    return new Buffer( result ).toString('base64');
};
```

And in Laravel I have:

```
<?php
function encrypt($key = "9055935C641A3CD243337FD149C793DF", $data) {
    $encrypter = new Encrypter($key, 'AES-128-CBC');
    $dataEncrypted = $encrypter->encryptString($data);
    return $dataEncrypted;
}
```

The problem is that I get an error on Laravel states: `The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.`

How can I use the key that I use on Node.js in Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues with the PHP code:

1. You're using `$this->key` instead of `$key`
2. `Encrypter()` appears to be expecting a binary string (not a string of hex characters), so you need to decode the hex first (e.g. using [`hex2bin()`](http://php.net/hex2bin)).