# Laravel and node js encryption

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel, encryption

**Update:**

```
var key = new Buffer('laravel app ', 'base64');
var json =  JSON.parse(new Buffer(password_encrypted,'base64').toString('utf8'));
var _iv =   new Buffer(json.iv , 'base64');
var decipher  = crypto.createDecipheriv('AES-256-CBC', key, _iv);
decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
var t = new Buffer(json.value,'base64');
var dec = decipher.update(t) + decipher.final();
console.log(dec);
```

So i got it working with the code above. Now the problem is the output is showing additional characters.

```
output : "s:8:\"asd123\";\u0001"
the password is asd123

s:x seems to be the size, any idea how to remove this?
```

i only want to extract the password, maybe im missing some settings in crypto?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972672/encryption-between-node-js-and-laravel-converting-code

Comment: yes, but i dont have idea how to use it on decrypting.

Comment: If you're experiencing differing outputs, you should be posting code snippets for *both* sides, not just one (e.g. just node). Also, the built-in `crypto` module in node is all you need.

Comment: https://github.com/illuminate/encryption/blob/master/Encrypter.php

this is the encrypter used in laravel